# How do I define and use an ENUM in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c

I declared an enum in my implementation file as shown below, and declared a variable of that type in my interface as PlayerState thePlayerState; and used the variable in my methods. But I am getting errors stating that it is undeclared. How do I correctly declare and use a variable of type PlayerState in my methods?:

In the .m file

```
@implementation View1Controller

    typedef enum playerStateTypes
        {
            PLAYER_OFF,
            PLAYER_PLAYING,
            PLAYER_PAUSED
        } PlayerState;
```

in the .h file:

```
@interface View1Controller : UIViewController {

    PlayerState thePlayerState;
```

in some method in .m file:

```
-(void)doSomethin{

thePlayerState = PLAYER_OFF;

}
```

Comment: Now the type of the enum is thePlayerState. What does playerStateTypes become?

Comment: For information about NS_ENUM and its latest modern syntax, see the posting [NS_ENUM & NS_OPTIONS](http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/) by Mattt Thompson.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Your `typedef` needs to be in the header file (or some other file that's `#import`ed into your header), because otherwise the compiler won't know what size to make the `PlayerState` ivar.  Other than that, it looks ok to me.

Comment: The option to put it in a separate file seemed right in my case. I don't know if this is a good approach, but I needed to use the same enum in two different ViewControllers (self and it's delegate/datasource). Importing the header of the delegate/datasource resulted in an error and seems too much for a simple need. So I created a new .h file with the enum declared and imported it on both viewControllers.h file. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Should recommend to use the NS_ENUM macro - since this is best practice

Comment: You must declare enums using `NS_ENUM` in Objective-C if you want your enum to be available in Swift code.

Comment: @DaveDeLong, Is this still valid in 2015? I have the `typedef` declared in the `.m` file and it compiles and runs well.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei it would go in the .h file if you need to use the enum in other files. If you only need it in one file, putting it in the .m file has always been perfectly fine.

Comment: @DaveDeLong, Understood.

Answer (score 214):

Apple provides a macro to help provide better code compatibility, including Swift. Using the macro looks like this.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, PlayerStateType) {
  PlayerStateOff,
  PlayerStatePlaying,
  PlayerStatePaused
};
```

[Documented here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html)

Comment: Can Obj C Enums have member variables like they can in Java? If so, how?

Comment: So the second solution is better?

Comment: The second solution is better (using `NS_ENUM`), as it is more modern, and is now required in Objective-C if you want your enum to be available in Swift code.

Comment: Updated to show the second solution is in fact better.

Comment: In Apple's standard form, the type name is repeated for each enum value.

Comment: @ThomasW do you have some documentation you can link to for this?

Comment: Actually the documentation you're pointing to says that implicitly when it says "The prefixes to C enumeration case names are removed when they are imported into Swift". All of Apple's headers have that form.

Answer (score 29):

In the .h:

```
typedef enum {
    PlayerStateOff,
    PlayerStatePlaying,
    PlayerStatePaused
} PlayerState;
```

Comment: You can find an answer like this in other SO questions, but when I was reviewing enums, this question popped up first, so I added the answer here too.

Answer (score 20):

With current projects you may want to use the `NS_ENUM()` or `NS_OPTIONS()` macros.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, PlayerState) {
        PLAYER_OFF,
        PLAYER_PLAYING,
        PLAYER_PAUSED
    };
```

Comment: ...and more importantly now, you must declare enums using `NS_ENUM` in Objective-C if you want your enum to be available in Swift code.

Answer (score 17):

This is how Apple does it for classes like NSString:

In the header file:

```
enum {
    PlayerStateOff,
    PlayerStatePlaying,
    PlayerStatePaused
};

typedef NSInteger PlayerState;
```

Refer to Coding Guidelines at http://developer.apple.com/

Comment: This doesn't actually help the OP. While technically correct, it doesn't tell them how to create a reusable enum

Comment: Linking to developer.apple.com is not real helpful.  Is there some other place you'd like to cite instead?

Comment: Copy/paste documentation which has already given, the link which is the main page is really not helping to another people...

Comment: This is now out of date, see this page https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html

Answer (score 9):

I recommend using NS_OPTIONS or NS_ENUM. You can read more about it here: http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/

Here's an example from my own code using NS_OPTIONS, I have an utility that sets a sublayer (CALayer) on a UIView's layer to create a border.

The h. file:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, BSTCMBorder) {
    BSTCMBOrderNoBorder     = 0,
    BSTCMBorderTop          = 1 << 0,
    BSTCMBorderRight        = 1 << 1,
    BSTCMBorderBottom       = 1 << 2,
    BSTCMBOrderLeft         = 1 << 3
};

@interface BSTCMBorderUtility : NSObject

+ (void)setBorderOnView:(UIView *)view
                 border:(BSTCMBorder)border
                  width:(CGFloat)width
                  color:(UIColor *)color;

@end
```

The .m file:

```
@implementation BSTCMBorderUtility

+ (void)setBorderOnView:(UIView *)view
                 border:(BSTCMBorder)border
                  width:(CGFloat)width
                  color:(UIColor *)color
{

    // Make a left border on the view
    if (border & BSTCMBOrderLeft) {

    }

    // Make a right border on the view
    if (border & BSTCMBorderRight) {

    }

    // Etc

}

@end
```